# advance search mysql query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on advance search functionality, where people able to search recipe using advance search.
For that i have these database structures,

**1)recipe**

```
id   title
1    banana
2    orange
```

**2)filter_main_category**

```
id    name
1     ingredients
2     restrictions
3     cuisines
4     meal_type
```

**3)sub_cat**

```
id    name
1     bread
2     breakfast
3     dinner
4     banana
5     butter
6     eggs
```

**4)relations**

```
id    recipe_id    main_category_id    sub_cat_id
1     1            4                   4
2     1            4                   6
3     1            2                   6
```

So, according to table, you can see `recipe_id` 1 has 3 filters
where two with `main_category_id` 4 and one with `main_category_id` 2.

Now, if user select `main_category_id` = 4 and sub_cat_id = 4,6 in advance search then we have so show that results like this,

```
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE main_category_id = 4 AND sub_cat_id IN (4,6)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id    recipe_id    main_category_id    sub_cat_id
1     1            4                   4
2     1            4                   6
```

Now, if user also select `main_category_id` = 2 and `sub_cat_id` = 6 from advance filter(main_category_id=2 is for restriction, so we have to remove recipe from search result if user select this filter), then we have to remove last record from output(because main_category_id = 2 so we have to restrict sub category from search)

For this what i am trying is,

```
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE (main_category_id = 4 AND sub_cat_id IN (4,6)) AND ( main_category_id = 2 AND sub_cat_id NOT IN (6) )
```

But its returning wrong result,

What should i want in output is

```
id    recipe_id    main_category_id    sub_cat_id
1     1            4                   4
```

Is there any solution to do like this?

Comment: Do not query for main_category_id = 2. This will solve your problem.

Comment: so how can i know that if i have to use `IN` or `NOT IN` without `main_category`. because it depends on `main_category`

Comment: need to use some php code to filter the query like if `main_category = 2` then restrict the main category selection

Comment: agreed with @JitendraPurohit

Comment: yes that will do my job. but is there any solution to play only with MySQL query?

Comment: No, I don't think the approach will be good there, as you need to decide the output based on the value resided in another table and filter the search result.